# check if value is an integer (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I check if my value is a integer or not?
I want something like this:

```
if ( i/split != int )  {...}
```

Thanks,

Comment: 'i' will be an integer who will change like 1,2,3,4 and 'split' = 2

Comment: This should be if (i/split != integer) NOT if (i/split != int)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you're trying to find out if the result of the divide is a whole number.  You can use modulus operator % to get the remainder from the divide operation.

Assuming `i` and `split` are integer types (int, long, short, etc), then modulus returns 0 when `i` or `split` is an integer value, ie:

```
if ( i % split == 0 ) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the *objCType* method?
[Docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/objCType)